# Need to display validation error message about Mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to display an error message about the mobile phone number on following conditions:
a) It should contain 10 digits.
b) It should not start with 0 or 1.
c) All the 10 digits should not be same. Example:"(222)-2222-222".

Below is the html and js code.

```
<label>Work Phone</label>
                                    <input id="" type="text" ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" name="workPhone"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           tabindex="16"
                                           ng-model="patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers['work']"
                                           ng-change="setPhoneNumber('work')"
                                           ui-mask-placeholder-char="space"
                                           model-view-value="true"/>
                                    <p ng-show="(frmPatientEdit.$submitted && frmPatientEdit.workPhone.$invalid) || (frmPatientEdit.workPhone.$invalid && frmPatientEdit.workPhone.$touched)"
                                       class="error">Work Phone is Invalid.</p>
```

JS Code:

```
 $scope.setPhoneNumber = function (type) {

            if (typeof $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers[type] !== "undefined" && $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers[type] !== "") {

                var obj = $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers.filter(function (item) {
                    return item.type === type;
                });

                var index = $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers.indexOf(obj[0]);

                if (index > -1) {

                    $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers[index].number = $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers[type];

                } else {
                    //console.log('Adding number: ', $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers[type], type);
                    $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers.push({"type": type, "number": $scope.patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers[type]});

                }
            }



        };
```

Comment: Try this:  https://jsfiddle.net/uwpwx/529/

Comment: @NNR - This Regex is failing for the condition say "2888888888". Put the first digit between 2-9 and repeat the rest 9 digits. It will fail.

Comment: Yeah. You are right.

Comment: @NNR- can you please help me in forming the correct regex with all the 3 conditions?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

**Html :**

```
<ng-form name="myForm" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div>Phone No :</div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="9101234567" name="phone" minlength="10" maxlength="10" ng-pattern="phoneNumbr" ng-model="phone"/>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$error.minlength">Phone no not less that 10 char.</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$error.maxlength">Phone no not more than 10 char.</span>
      <br><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$error.pattern">Please match pattern [9101234567]</span>
    </div>
  </ng-form>
```

**Script :**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.phoneNumbr = /^([2-9])(?!\1+$)\d{9}$/;
});
```

Here, Out of `10` digits `1` is consumed by first position `2-9` and then next 9 digits can be from `0-9`.

**Requirement fulfillment :**

a) It should contain 10 digits. - **Achieved**

b) It should not start with 0 or 1. - **Achieved**

c) All the 10 digits should not be same. - **Achieved**

**Working fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/rohitjindal/p0rcwon2/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a combination of Regular Expressions and JavaScript.

The regex will take care of:

1. It should not start with 0 or 1
2. It should contain 10 digits

The JavaScript code will take care of:

1. All the 10 digits should not be the same

Here is the function:

```
function validatePhone(p){

    p = ''+p; //convert it to a string

    var regex = /^[2-9]\d{9}$/;

    return regex.test(Number(p)) && p.split('').reverse().join('') !== p
}
```